# Unable to clear the form after submitting and showing the previously entered data using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I had one textarea and a button beside it.When i click the button a modal window opens,which contains a textarea.I will enter some message and press submit,then the message should be displayed in textarea which is outside the modal window,which iam able to do.But when again i click on button,it is still showing the previously entered message.I'm unable to clear that even after using a clear function for ng-submit.I appreciate some one to help me.

```js
angular.module('ui-rangeSlider', [])
.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
     replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  })
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', ['ui-rangeSlider']);
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
     
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        
    }; 
    $scope.submitToggle = true;  
    //default get the data
    
//send post, saving to localStorage     
$scope.sendPost = function(test) {
//setting the data to the textara
    $scope.hello = test;
    $scope.hello1 = test;
    
    $scope.clear();
    

   /* //saving the data 
     return localstore.setData(test);
   */            
            };
            $scope.clear=function(){
             
             
                       $scope.test = null;
            };
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



 <body ng-app="mymodal">   
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
      <textarea ng-model="hello">{{test}}</textarea>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button>
    
  <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">

 <form>
 <textarea ng-model="test" class="form-control" id="text" name="modaltext" placeholder="Type in your message" rows="5" maxlength="200"></textarea>
   
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="sendPost(test);clear()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
      <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
   </form>
     
   </modal>
 </div>  
 </body>
```

/`http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/5562/`

Answer (score 0):

You can access and clear the `test` text when calling the function to open the modal, like this:

`scope.$$nextSibling.test = '';`

http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/5632/

**Edit:**
Now it also resets the remaining characters to 99.

Comment: Hey Alves,Thanks for your comment.I tried that but am unable to fix that..Can use please edit in that jsfiddle url and post the link.may be am doing something wrong.Even if you observe the character count is not changing....Thanks